# HDD doesn't work on reboot

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, bios, sata

I have a computer with 2 hard drives, one is SSD and the other is HDD, both with windows 10.

When I got the PC I installed windows on HDD first and then SSD, so the windows boot manager is on the HDD.

The problem is if I start the computer after being completely off then the HDD is recognized in bios and everything works, however when I restart the PC "doesn't matter if from HDD or SSD windows" then the HDD is not recognized in the bios and I cannot access anything until I turn off and on the PC.

Is there any more information needed?

My computer specs are :

```
- Intel Core i7 7700 3.6Ghz
- Asus Prime B250M-K LGA115 DDR4
- Kingston SSDNow UV400 240GB SATA III
- Western Digital Caviar Black WD2003FZEX 2TB SATA III
```

How do I fix this?

EDIT:

Boot order is:

```
1- SSD
2- HDD
3- DVDROM
```

Sata Information:

```
SATA6G_1: N/A
SATA6G_2: N/A
SATA6G_3: N/A
SATA6G_4: KINGSTON SSD
SATA6G_5: WDC 2T HDD
SATA6G_6: DVDRAM
```

Comment: SATA drives have their own cable each. So there is no master and slave. Or do you use IDE cables and SATA to IDE adapters?

Comment: You are right, i checked the internet about the IDE and no there is no any IDE in the computer, I will remove the part that says master and slave from the question.

Comment: I would start by plugging the SSD into SATA6G_1 incase their is a mistake in the BIOS code regarding the boot order vs plug order.

Comment: I cannot plug it into SATA6G_1 -> _3 because the GPU is taking much space, anyway i flipped between the SSD and HDD but still same problem